# Regular Exp find duplicate phrases 2 sequentially words in a pattern

Tags: php, regex, duplicates

I would like to catch 2 words sequentially duplicated in a pattern

I would like to be able to catch duplicate words in this case `"cancer cervical"` because they are the only duplicate 2 words sequentially.

pattern `"cancer cervical diane mortality cervical cancer cervical diane sea"`

I use this Regular expression but still can't catch 2 sequentially duplicated words.

```
/(\W|^)(.+)\s\2/ig
```

Comment: why not servical diane, it is also repeated?

Comment: Do you mean **part** of a word is repeated? As in the `cer` at the end of `cancer` matching the `cer` at the start of `cervical`?

Comment: Why not `cancer cervical diane`? they are repeated

Comment: yes you are right "cancer cervical diane" in this case repeated.

Comment: can you try `/(\b\w+\s\w+\b).+?\1/` if you only need

Comment: yes group of words should be catched

Comment: What if the words are in a different order the second time? Is it still a match since it's written twice or does it have to be 2+ words in the same order?

Comment: @Onyambu let me test and get back to you seems working.

Comment: @andreas yes same order

Comment: That is only working for two words not more than two.  what if we have something like `cancer cervical diane cancer mortality cervical cancer cervical diane sea"` Now here `cancer` is repeated 3 times while the phrase `cancer cervical diane ` is repeated. What do you want?

Comment: for the three words in this line we would have `/(.+).*\1/` or even `(\b.+\b).*?\1`

Comment: @Onyambu I don't want to catch only 1 word but 2 or more sequentially

Comment: @Onyambu I guess /(\b\w+\s\w+\b).+?\1/  would work let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be able to do the job:  `/(\w+\s\w.*)\s.*\1/` if you are dealing with words including numbers.

```js
var string = "cancer cervical diane mortality cervical cancer cervical diane sea";
var regex = /(\w+\s\w.*)\s.*\1/;
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

```js
var string = "cancer cervical diane mortality cervical cancer cervical diane sea";
var string1=" this is a test cancer cervical cancer diane mortality cervical cancer cervical diane sea";
var string2=" test whether it will catch one word cancer mortality cervical cancer cervical diane sea";
var regex = /(\w+\s\w.*)\s.*\1/;
console.log(string.match(regex));
console.log(string1.match(regex));
console.log(string2.match(regex));
```

Comment: it works perfectly I tried on this website.
https://www.regextester.com/?fam=103328

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're simply looking for `/(.+)\s\1/`.

This will match any character(s) that are separated by a space.

In your example, it will match the `cer` of both `cancer` and `cervical`:

```js
var string = "cancer cervical diane mortality cervical cancer cervical diane sea";
var regex = /(.+)\s\1/;
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

This can also be seen working on **[Regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/CdX2u2/1/)**.